# Python: write values in loop to csv

Tags: python, csv

I try to write some values in the loop, but my csv file is empty.

I have df

```
domain  surname name    patronymic
erlyvideo.ru    Лапшина Юлия    Юрьевна
finteca.ru  Крылов  Александр   Александрович
```

I use

```
with open('emails.csv','w') as f1:
writer = csv.writer(f1)
for i, (sur, name, patr, dom) in enumerate(zip(df.surname.values.tolist(), df.name.values.tolist(), df.patronymic.values.tolist(), df.domain.values.tolist())):
    sur = translit(sur, "ru", reversed=True).replace("'", '')
    name = translit(name, "ru", reversed=True).replace("'", '')
    patr = translit(patr, "ru", reversed=True).replace("'", '')
    all_email = []
    var0 = 'edevyataykina' + '@' + str(dom)
    var1 = str(sur) + '@' + str(dom)
    var2 = str(name) + '@' + str(dom)

    all_email.extend([var1, var2])
    if validate_email(var0, check_mx=True) == True and validate_email(var0, verify=True) == True:
        res_mail = 'Catch_All'
    elif validate_email(var0, check_mx=True) == False:
        res_mail = 'DomainName Not Found'
    elif validate_email(var0, check_mx=True) == True and validate_email(var0, verify=True) == None:
        valid_email = []
        for mail in all_email:
            is_valid = validate_email(mail, verify=True)
            time.sleep(1)
            if is_valid is True:
                valid_email.append(mail)
        if len(valid_email) == 1:
            res_mail = valid_email[0]
        else:
            res_mail = 'Username Not Found'
            print res_mail
    writer.writerow(res_mail)
```

Why can I write all values `res_mail` to csv in loop or to text_file?

Comment: did you get error message when you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Always put in question full error message. `writerow` expect list with columns

Comment: if `df` means `pandas` then you have `df.to_csv(filename)`

Comment: @furas I don't have any error. It creates a file `emails.csv` but it's empty

Comment: @furas `df` is pandas. Why I should `df.to_csv(filename)`? `res_mail` is a string. I want to write strings to `csv` in this loop

Comment: you should get error because `writerow` expect list but you use single text. Then put some `print()` in code to see which part is executed. Maybe it never write in filr.

Comment: you can create new `df` with expected columns and then easily write it using `to_csv()`

Comment: I have many lines in df and it takes many time. So I want to write lines in loop.@furas I want to fix my code

Comment: Not relevant, but something like `if validate_this(x,y, z) == True and validate_that(a, b) == False` can be written as `if validate_this(x,y,z) and not validate_that(a,b)`

Comment: @PetrPetrov You can write the large dataframe object to the file in chunks. Check the `chunks` argument in `df.to_csv()`

Comment: I don't need to use a chunk. I meant that I have ~500 domains and I have max `var28`. And it takes many times to check mails@MYGz

Comment: ~500 is not so much for pandas which use fast C/C++ code in background. BTW: `open('w')` deletes old data so maybe you open again with `w` mode and delete it. `zip` may create elmpty list and `for` is never executed. So first think is check it - you can use `print()` to see which part is executed. BTW: we can't run your code to check how it works so we can't give you ideal solution.

Comment: do not use the `csv` module to begin with if you just want to write a string in each line. Also indent your code properly. Everything below `with` should be indented further. Finally de-indent `res_mail` twice to see what you get in all cases, not just the last. Notice that you have no `else` in your outer `if`. If none of the `if` or`elif`s trigger `res_mail` will remain undefined and the code will crash with `NameError`